# Is there an equivalent to Python's all function in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Python the `all()` functions tests if all values in a list are true. For example, I can write

```
if all(x < 5 for x in [1, 2, 3, 4]):
    print("This always happens")
else:
    print("This never happens")
```

Is there an equivalent function in JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, it does exist: [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).
Example from mdn:

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
    return (element >= 10);
}
var passed = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough);
// passed is false
passed = [12, 54, 18, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough);
// passed is true
```

This means you won't have to write it manually. This function doesn't work on IE8-, though.

However, if you want a function that also works for IE8-, you can use a manual implementation, 
[**Or the polyfill shown on the mdn page**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Compatibility).

Manual:

```
function all(array, condition){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(!condition(array[i])){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
all([1, 2, 3, 4], function(e){return e < 3}) // false
all([1, 2, 3, 4], function(e){return e > 0}) // true
```

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: Oh derp, I didn't know about that one. Added it to my answer, cleaning the rest up right now.

Comment: Worth mentioning: there's also the opposite: `Array.prototype.some`, which checks if *any* of the value passes the test.